# How to stop Moment.js from automatically creating a moment object when you type 'a' or 'p' after a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using Moment in a project, but want to be able to type a date into the input.For some reason, after I type in a valid date/time, my input is completely changing when I start typing 'a' or 'p' for am and pm.

For instance, I can type 03-15-2018 2:00 just fine, but when I space and type 'a' or 'p' (only those letters), my input suddenly turns into something like this: Thu Mar 15 2018 14:00:00 GMT-0400. At that point, the input changes from a string to a moment object.

I'm trying to split the input up and run validations on date and time separately, so this is really messing me up. Not to mention I don't want the user to have to deal with this annoyance. Does anyone have any idea where this is occurring and how it can be stopped?

Comment: You should consider posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve